# How to do the transition of Youtube app on search?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, transition

Is this possible to achieve only on editing xml? Noticing how the toolbar shrinks to the size of the search's toolbar upon startActivity.

[image]

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Can anyone provide ideas on this question?